# I have a problem with my code. I doesn't display the list

Tags: c, linked-list

This code is a linked list, that displays the inputted list and will delete number in the list, but when I print the list it doesn't display. My code is shown below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

// A linked list node

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a
list and an int, inserts a new node on the front of the
list. */

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = new_data;
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);
    (*head_ref) = new_node;
}
```

/* Given a reference (pointer to pointer) to the head of a
list and a key, deletes the first occurrence of key in
linked list */

```
void deleteNode(struct Node** head_ref, int key)
{

    // Store head node
    struct Node *temp = *head_ref, *prev;
 
    // If head node itself holds the key to be deleted
    if (temp != NULL && temp->data == key) {
        *head_ref = temp->next; // Changed head
        free(temp); // free old head
        return;
    }
 
    // Search for the key to be deleted, keep track of the
    // previous node as we need to change 'prev->next'
    while (temp != NULL && temp->data != key) {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
 
    // If key was not present in linked list
    if (temp == NULL)
        return;
 
    // Unlink the node from linked list
    prev->next = temp->next;
 
    free(temp); // Free memory
}
```

// This function prints contents of linked list starting
// from the given node

```
void printList(struct Node* node)
{

    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("%d  ", node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```

// Driver code

```
int main()
{
    /* Start with the empty list */
    struct Node* node;
    
    int key;
    printf("Enter 10 integers: \n");
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    scanf("%d", &key);
    }
    
    printf("Entered Elements within the List\n\n");
     printList(node);
     
    printf("\nEnter the element to be deleted: \n");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    
    deleteNode(&node, &key);
    printf("\nLinked List after Deletion of %d: \n", key);
    printList(node);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You never add the nodes to the list

Comment: Is there a full code in question?

Comment: oww lol! @mousetail

Comment: @mousetail can you fix the code I'm struggling.... please

Comment: Hint: look at the code for `push()`... Maybe you want to call that function somewhere.

Comment: @Fe2O3 it work but there's an another error hahahah. can you help me??